# Pushing gestures Data programatically onto the raw folder

Tags: android

I want to push the data stored in the gestureslibrary onto my raw folder in the project.I want to do this in my program via code and not manually.How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

An application's apk file and the folders it contains are not writable by the application.  You will have to store the information in private storage or external storage.

If you mean you want to automatically include something when building the application, look into extending your build system (IDE or ant) with a custom script.